# Failure to compile "hello world" web server app with Poco

Tags: mfc, poco-libraries

When I search Google for "poco web server example", the very first link it offers me is [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/252827/Learning-Poco-A-simple-HTTP-server). Now admittedly it has a zero star rating, and Google offers a more official example from Poco one step down the list. Nonetheless, the example is tantalisingly simple, so I tried to add it to an existing (MFC) project and compile it. When I do, I get these errors:

```
[...]serverapplication.h(215): error C3646: '_serviceStatus': unknown override specifier
[...]serverapplication.h(215): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[...]serverapplication.h(216): error C3646: '_serviceStatusHandle': unknown override specifier
[...]serverapplication.h(216): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

The errors occur on these two lines in `serverapplication.h`:

```
static SERVICE_STATUS        _serviceStatus; 
static SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE _serviceStatusHandle;
```

Naturally, the errors persist even when all I do is include the Poco header files and nothing else... so it's not as if *my code* has a problem, it's more that *my environment* has a problem. Indeed, I get precisely the same errors if I replace the list of 8 Poco header files + 3 STL headers with the longer list from Poco's own HTTPTimeServer example (which compiles and runs fine as an independent project by the way).

It looks like `SERVICE_STATUS` and `SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE` are being #defined to nothing at all. Is there a compiler setting or preprocessor definition that would do this? What is the trap that Poco users should beware of falling into? Are there compatibility issues between Poco and MFC?

**Update:** I can reproduce the issue independently of my application by downloading [this zipped project](http://pocoproject.org/files/misc/pocomfc.zip) referenced by [this potentially relevant article](http://pocoproject.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=4838)... which builds fine... but the moment I try to specify the extra include folder and include `serverapplication.h`, these errors occur. There is no mention of any dependencies on the Poco [ServerApplication](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Util.ServerApplication.html) class documentation page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include POCO's `ServerApplication.h` header file in an MFC project, try `#include <winsvc.h>` prior to `#include "ServerApplication.h"`. Note that you must not include `Windows.h` in an MFC project, which would normally include `winsvc.h`.

Answer (score 0):

`SERVICE_STATUS` is a structure defined in the Windows SDK.

The [SERVICE_STATUS structure documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicates to

> include Windows.h

Have you tried to `#include <Windows.h>`?

**Edit**
Since you're trying to add it to an MFC application, have you tried to add `#include "stdafx.h"`?

Comment: No I hadn't tried that... but it makes no difference. I can right-click on SERVICE_STATUS and go to its definition, which takes me to winsvc.h in both my faulty project, and the Poco example project that compiles fine. In short, Visual Studio seems to be fine with the definitions... until it comes time to actually compile them.

Comment: Check/compare the project configurations of your existing project and the one from the example project. There's probably a difference like the use of MFC and/or the target platform toolset.

Comment: Yes - it appears that there are issues with the use of MFC - from what I'm reading, that appears to be a critical compatibility issue that was not particularly clear. I'll edit my question to reflect it

Comment: Try to `#include "stdafx.h"` since you're trying to add it to an MFC project.

Comment: That's already there... and now [this link](http://pocoproject.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=4838) has shown me a working MFC dialog-based app (same style as mine)... but so far I haven't found a combination of settings that eliminates the error :-(

Comment: The file `"stdafx.h"` file is unrelated to MFC. It is the default file name used for precompiled headers. MFC applications must `#include <afx.h>`.

Comment: The standard-issue stdafx.h for an MFC dialog app includes afxwin.h, which in turn includes afx.h... so this seems like a red herring. What I do know is that when I include serverapplication.h, it does not (yet) define SERVICE_STATUS. Nor is it defined after the inclusion of the 3-4 Poco header files. I'm currently trying to find the point at which it gets defined in a project that compiles...