# Using #ifdef or #if defined() to find where a variable is (not) defined

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a situation in which `#ifdef` is telling me that something is not defined, and yet it proceeds to compile a line as if it is defined. I can't figure out how that can be.

The wider context is that I am banging my head against a brick wall trying to resolve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353592/failure-to-compile-hello-world-web-server-app-with-poco). I am trying to determine the point at which `SERVICE_STATUS` is defined in both a project that compiles, and one that doesn't. As far as Visual Studio 2015 is concerned, if I right click on the word `SERVICE_STATUS` and go to its definition, in both cases I am taken to the same file: winsvc.h. So I don't think that paths are an issue.

All of which has led me to introducing the following five-line check in various places to see if I can understand where `SERVICE_STATUS` is included/defined:

```
#if defined(SERVICE_STATUS)    // or #ifdef SERVICE_STATUS
#pragma message( "SS is defined" )
#else
#pragma message( "SS is NOT defined" )
#endif
```

In all cases, including just prior to the point where `SERVICE_STATUS` is used in both the compiling and the non-compiling cases, the only message ever printed is **SS is NOT defined**. This is the line that does or does not compile, and I can prove it is being parsed by causing deliberate errors immediately before it:

```
static SERVICE_STATUS _serviceStatus;
```

Has my head been banged too many times to notice the obvious schoolboy error in my usage of `#ifdef` or `#if defined()` (I've tried both)? Alternatively, how this could possibly compile if `SERVICE_STATUS` is undefined?

Here's a sketch of the context in which this occurs (in the file serverapplication.h from the Poco distribution at pocoproject.org):

```
...    // lots of irrelevant lines omitted...
[5LC]  // apply my 5-line check
#include <ThisFile>
#include <ThatFile>
[5LC]  // check again and find no change due to header inclusion
...    // many more lines skipped...
[5LC]  // one last check prior to using SERVICE_STATUS - still no change
static SERVICE_STATUS _serviceStatus;  // variable results!?!?
```

If you want the full context, see [the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353592/failure-to-compile-hello-world-web-server-app-with-poco) I'm trying to fix for links to a zipped project in which I have been able to reproduce this problem independent of my own project... but please respond to that issue separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SERVICE_STATUS` is a type definition that was defined with `typedef`; the answer in your other question contains a link to the documentation of it.

`#ifdef` is only used to determine if a name was defined as a macro with `#define` (or via compiler options), you can't use it to test whether a type, variable, or function has been defined. It's part of the preprocessor, not the compiler, so it doesn't know anything about those elements of the code.

Comment: Thanks - really clear... unlike my brain just now. So how does one trace back to where a variable is or is not defined?

Comment: You can't. The only way to see whether a type is defined is to try to use it and see if compilation fails.

Comment: @omatai It seems like VS tried to do that for you. I'm not sure why you think it was wrong.

Comment: It's not that I think it was "wrong" so much as I fail to understand how it can be that on two separate projects, VS can go to the definition of a type, and goes to exactly the same place, yet one project compiles as if the type is defined, and the other compiles as if it is not. I would have thought that "go to definition" ought to succeed only when something is actually defined.

Comment: There's nothing in the question that indicates that the failure to compile is related to whether this type is defined.

Answer (score 4):

Those two *preprocessor* directives tell you *only*, whether `SERVICE_STATUS` is defined as a preprocessor macro, i.e. if there is a line saying `#define SERVICE_STATUS something` somewhere before the `#ifdef`. That is not the same as  "defined" in the non-preprocessor sense.

Answer (score 2):

`SERVICE_STATUS` [is a `struct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996(v=vs.85).aspx), not a macro (despite the horribly misleading name). So it can't be detected by the preprocessor.

Answer (score -1):

It seems not possible yet, for instance VS14. This is a pity.